# TypeScript type definition for flatten function

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have simple `flatten` function. The idea is that it can take array of strings or array of arrays of strings and always return just 1 level array of strings. For example:

```
flatten(['a', ['b']]) // returns ['a', 'b']
flatten(['a', 'b']) // returns ['a', 'b']
```

Here is implementation of this function

```
function flatten(arr: ReadonlyArray<string | string[]>): string[] {
   return [].concat(...arr);
}
```

I'm getting following TypeScript compiler Error:

```
  error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
    Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
      Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
    Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
      Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ConcatArray<never>'.

  105   return [].concat(...arr);
                        ~~~~~~
```

How can I define types for input and output of this `flatten` function? I want to avoid using `any` type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm thinking the compiler can't figure out what array type the `[]` value is supposed to be.  The easiest workaround here is to tell it that it's a `string[]` with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function flatten(arr: ReadonlyArray<string | string[]>): string[] {
   return ([] as string[]).concat(...arr);
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMANgQylApmAFGgJwIC5EAlLNAEwRQE8BBItOgHgGcoCYwBzRAD6JO3PgG0AugD4AlKRE9ekxAG8AUIk0EsUEASS5ladsK6LJMgHQQEEDLkuPCBGQG41AXzU2w7OCixLFDheXFQMbDwxAHI0aIAaRBiAI2iJCRkZRAB6bMRtXX0TGLjE6NSJbwQ-AKCQsPRMHENYhMRytMycvIK9XyTWsoqgA)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type for the returned value, in this case, an array of strings.

```
function flatten(arr: ReadonlyArray<string | string[]>): string[] {
    const output: string[] = [];
    return output.concat(...arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for flatting arrays of arbitrary depth and arbitrary types here is a solution:

```
type ExtractLeafTypes<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U> ? ExtractLeafTypes<U> : T
function deepFlatten<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>>(arr: T): Array<ExtractLeafTypes<T>> {
    return arr.reduce((acc, n) => acc.concat(Array.isArray(n) ? deepFlatten(n) : [n]) , [])
}

const numbers = [1, [2], [[3]], [[[[4]]]]]
const flatNumbers = deepFlatten(numbers) // : number[]
const mixed = [1, ['a', ['b'], [[[[[[['c']]]]]]]], [2, [3, [[[[[[[[[[4]]]]]]]]]]]]]
const flatMixed = deepFlatten(mixed) // : (number | string)[]
const strict = [1, ['a', ['b'], [[[[[[['c']]]]]]]], [2, [3, [[[[[[[[[[4]]]]]]]]]]]]] as const
const flatStrict = deepFlatten(strict) // :  (1 | "a" | "b" | "c" | 3 | 2 | 4)[]
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbADIWQMwCrgQDOAPHgHxQC8UeUECEAdgCZFQBK2LA9kwDYgAgohQgSASyY4IiKAFVKAflgIU6LLgKRSiqAC5aAWABQOAK5N0EvlBYQIYAGL9kwYMzL1Grdl2S8AsKiyOLITCDk5AAUyKKGeACUhiJiJPBIaJjY+ISkFJQA3qZQpVCIEMDmiExQcYgAdBUs5qgQ0bGoqAA0UEyJ1JRoqA2ofKhu0amhDRJE0yDR-VAq9o4ubh5MSwOGANpMALoDvXvHpgC+pqZjTETAfeYAtgBGsuw0ewCMpwBMh6c9gBmQ4AqB7CF7AAsoNhNz49ygOFcwAAcs83ogPnYHM4UVslhj3gMAPQkgyPV6yM7wu4PJ4SOAQFjUcE-cEAcmQHNOHJeHLBkKFHNQAth4r+pyBgKFQph4oVcJMt0RyLcAFlGczWWs8ZtmNEGUyWKTyYZCVS5AAfKD3RBSADmiRpyoRDztEnQrO+vO5vP5gtlexFYsVkvB0vBQch8sVCrq7BVwFpqpRAGUkJ6HjRdRt3AaPehTRSoNEvlAbQAiZCVitQSsvWtV1BNqBAuu-OtQ52HIA)