# Properly typing a filter & flatten function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Given the following function definition:

```
const filterNonUndefined = <T>(vals: (T | T[] | undefined)[]): T[] => {
    const nonUndefined = vals.filter((v): v is (T | T[]) => v !== undefined);
    return nonUndefined.flat();
};
```

The compiler complains that:

```
Type '(T | (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T))[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
  Type 'T | (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T)' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T)'.
```

To my understanding, `nonUndefined` has type `(T | T[])[]`. I would expect that flattening that would result in `T[]`.

I am not sure I understand why the error occurs and how I can properly fix it.

---

<sup>Please note that I have already reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307856/typescript-type-definition-for-flatten-function) and it does not answer my problem.</sup>

Comment: You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/flatten)

Answer (score 0):

If you add a temp variable for the final result, you will see that `.flat` returns a slightly more complex type than `T[]`. Although to me it does look like they are equivalent, TS does not think so. The working version is:

```
const filterNonUndefined = <T>(vals: (T | T[] | undefined)[]): (T | (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T))[] => {
    const nonUndefined = vals.filter((v): v is (T | T[]) => v !== undefined);
    const result = nonUndefined.flat();
    return result;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwDZQKYCcBy4CqYAmqiYq+MAvDADwAqAfABQBuAhkhAFwwM0wA+MGgG0AuvxgBXAkQQl8ASlHyuPcatQAPNAQgx0qFvnBIAnt1lwMMAJJgS6AILp0isQH4bdjE-QwuNeVcKOhgAbwAoGCiYUEhYMFxpYlIKGFZ2ADpEFAwGZmU0mARdVQFhEXlgwoBCckopQmSFAG5I6NjoPVQICRRUhLA8RtlSLKQWKAZ5VuiuqAl0MC6elFaAX2agA)

The inference of the deep array elements appears to be required so that the `.flat` function supports arrays with elements of mixed types.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the error is correct, as T may be an array

I would recommend to just remove the return type clause and lay on inferret return type which is correct

```
function nonNullable<T>(value: T | null | undefined): value is T {
  return value != null
}

const filterNonUndefined = <T>(vals: (T | T[] | undefined)[]) /* : auto */ => {
  // (T | (T extends readonly (infer InnerArr)[] ? InnerArr : T))[]
  return vals.filter(nonNullable).flat();
};

let a = filterNonUndefined([1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]])
//  ^?
// let a: number[]

let c = [1, 2, 3] as const;

let b = filterNonUndefined([c, c, c, [c, c, c]])
//  ^?
// let b: (1 | 2 | 3 | readonly [1, 2, 3])[]
```

If you must have return type (because `ts-eslint/return-types` or whatever), copy the inferred correct type from popup